# Ignore external points when finding rectangles

Tags: c#, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

I have some images like this where I need to find the central rectangle

[image]

Im using a variation of the EmguCV examples to find rectangles and came with this

```
using (MemStorage storage = new MemStorage())
{ //allocate storage for contour approximation

    //Contour<Point> contours = gray.FindContours()
    Contour<Point> contours = gray.FindContours(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,
     Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_LIST,
  storage);

    for (; contours != null; contours = contours.HNext)
    {
        Contour<Point> currentContour = contours.ApproxPoly(contours.Perimeter * 0.05, storage);
        //Seq<Point> currentContour = contours.GetConvexHull(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ORIENTATION.CV_CLOCKWISE);

        if (contours.Area > MinRectangleArea) //only consider contours with area greater than 20000
        {
            if (currentContour.Total == 4) //The contour has 4 vertices.
            {
                bool isRectangle = true;
                Point[] pts = currentContour.ToArray();
                LineSegment2D[] edges = PointCollection.PolyLine(pts, true);

                for (int i = 0; i < edges.Length; i++)
                {
                    double angle = Math.Abs(edges[(i + 1) % edges.Length].GetExteriorAngleDegree(edges[i]));
                    if (angle < 90 - RectangleAngleMargin  || angle > RectangleAngleMargin + 90)
                    {
                        isRectangle = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (isRectangle)
                {
                    boxList.Add(currentContour.GetMinAreaRect());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

And the result of executing that over those images sometimes finds this two rectangles:

[image]

The orange rectangle is ok, thats what I need. But I dont want the blue. Sometimes the four vertex are in the border of the image, usually one of them is out.

Changing the RETR_TYPE of the FindContours function to CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, I only get the blue rectangle, so I wonder if there is an option of NOT getting the contours with external points.

The real image actually can have smaller rectangles inside the orange (or a line appears splitting the rectangle), so after that I´m selecting the bigger rectangle to be the one I want, but cant do it that way with that blue one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a look at your sample image I would choose another approach.

Instead of classical contour detection, If you perform Hough line detection and then peform intersections of line found, you will find exactly the four vertices of the rectangle you are searching for...

If you need some help in coding let me know and I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The input image is in fact the result of a Hough line detection. A real image can actually have some "noisy" lines inside the rectangle (for example this: http://imgur.com/xQ8UVF0). With so many lines I would need to do a bunch of checks for the intersections and the position of the points obtained ending in a kinda bug prone code. At this point I am searching contours with CV_RETR_EXTERNAL and CV_RETR_SIMPLE methods and removing the external from the other set, but I guess that solution is better

Comment: Your scenario is more clear now. If you use CV_RETR_EXTERNAL it gives "outer" contours, so your blue contour enclosing the orange will be the one you get back.
If you want a better understanding on how contours are organized in opencv, here's a useful link: http://opencvpython.blogspot.it/2013/01/contours-5-hierarchy.html

Comment: Ok, I missunderstood the meaning of that parameter, I got it now. Seems like the findContours function is not the best option in my case, still dont know why it finds the blue rectangle though. Anyway will do it by checking intersections by hand.